# php pdo in class + best method to display return array

Tags: php, arrays, class, pdo

I have the following class:

```
<?php

class photos_profile {


  // Display UnApproved Profile Photos
  public $unapprovedProfilePhotosArray = array();
  public function displayUnapprovedProfilePhotos() {
    $users = new database('users');
    $sql='SELECT userid,profile_domainname,photo_name FROM login WHERE photo_verified=0 AND photo_name IS NOT NULL LIMIT 100;';
    $pds=$users->pdo->prepare($sql); $pds->execute(array()); $rows=$pds->fetchAll();

    $unapprovedProfilePhotosArray = $rows;

    echo 'inside the class now....';


    foreach($rows as $row) {
      echo $row['userid'];
    }
    }
}
```

I can display the data successfully from the foreach loop.

This is a class that is called as follows and want to be able to use the array in the display/view code. This why I added the "$unapprovedProfilePhotosArray = $rows;" but it doesn't work.

```
  $photos_profile = new photos_profile;
  $photos_profile->displayUnapprovedProfilePhotos();

      <?php
        foreach($photos_profile->unapprovedProfilePhotosArray as $row) {
          //print_r($photos_profile->unapprovedProfilePhotosArray);
          echo $row['userid'];
        }
      ?>
```

What is the best way for me to take the PHP PDO return array and use it in a view (return from class object). I could loop through all the values and populate a new array but this seems excessive.

Let me know if I should explain this better.

thx

Comment: Please don't edit your posts to completely remove the content. If you have solved your problem, you can either post the answer here for future visitors, or delete your question.

Comment: why you want to loop through all values to create a new array only to later loop again? does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the $this-> part. So basically you're creating a local variable inside the method named unapprovedProfilePhotosArray which disappears when the method finishes. If you want that array to stay in the property, then you should use $this->, which is the proper way to access that property.

```
...
$pds=$users->pdo->prepare($sql); $pds->execute(array()); $rows=$pds->fetchAll();

$this->unapprovedProfilePhotosArray = $rows;

...
```